# Ubuntu 17.10 Gimp 2.8 Can't export image

Tags: 17.10, gimp, image-processing

Installed gimp 2.8 from ubuntu repositories, I open an image, edit it, and try to export it to same format (jpg) to overwrite the existing image and I get this message:

```
JPEG image plug-in could not save image
```

Ubuntu 17.04 same gimp version worked just fine. This is now one more broken software among many in "new" Ubuntu.

Comment: I am unable to replicate this on my system.  What settings are you using in the export process?  If you use "Export As..." are you able to save the file under a different name?

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this behavior. Are you using 'Save,' 'Save As...,' Export As...' or Overwrite?

Comment: Overwriting same file that was opened. I need to investigate more since it's not happening for all files. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: What is the overall state of your system? Seen too many systems being abused by dpkg --force...

Answer (score 0):

I have faced to the same Problem  and I solved it by Activating the Swap partition, I think it caused by the low memory.

Comment: How do we activate the swap?